# How to retrieve data from multiple tables by multiple foreign keys in one query in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There is a model named Track:

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :profile_tracks
  has_many :favorite_tracks
  has_many :bookmark_tracks
  has_many :listened_tracks
end
```

And there is a model named Profile:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :profile_tracks
  has_many :favorite_tracks
  has_many :bookmark_tracks
  has_many :listened_tracks
end
```

I need to retrieve entries from those tables that share the same `track_id` and `profile_id` values. E.g.:

```
ProfileTrack.find_by(track_id: 1, profile_id: 1)
+
FavoriteTrack.find_by(track_id: 1, profile_id: 1)
+
BookmarkTrack.find_by(track_id: 1, profile_id: 1)
+
ListenedTrack.find_by(track_id: 1, profile_id: 1)
```

or

```
track = Track.find_by(id: 1)

track.profile_tracks.find_by(profile_id: 1)
+
track.favorite_tracks.find_by(profile_id: 1)
+
track.bookmark_tracks.find_by(profile_id: 1)
+
track.listened_tracks.find_by(profile_id: 1)
```

or

```
profile = Profile.find_by(id: 1)

profile.profile_tracks.find_by(track_id: 1)
+
profile.favorite_tracks.find_by(track_id: 1)
+
profile.bookmark_tracks.find_by(track_id: 1)
+
profile.listened_tracks.find_by(track_id: 1)
```

and return something like this:

```
{
  profile_track_id: some_id,
  favorite_track_id: some_id,
  bookmark_track_id: some_id,
  listened_track_id: some_id
}
```

or ActiveRecord model with these ids.

How can I do it **in one query**?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to create a some kind of music playlist app? You might want to change your `has_many` in Track to `belongs_to`, but it depends on your other models.
Anyway, you should be able to access them directly by using [joins](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins).

```rb
track = Track.joins(:profile_tracks, :favorite_tracks, :bookmark_tracks, 
                    :listened_tracks).find_by(id: 1)
```

You can use `find(1)` and this will raise an error if not found, `find_by(id:1)` will return nil.
Then in your hash

```rb
{
  profile_track_id: track.profile_track_id,
  favorite_track_id: track.favorite_track_id,
  bookmark_track_id: track.bookmark_track_id,
  listened_track_id: track.listened_track_id
}
```

---

### Update

To align with the question, as the above was wrong answer but still might be useful.

```rb
track = Track.joins(:profile_tracks, :favorite_tracks, :bookmark_tracks, 
                    :listened_tracks, :profiles).where(profiles: {id: 1})
```

This will produce below query

```
SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" 
INNER JOIN "profile_tracks" ON "profile_tracks"."track_id" = "tracks"."id"
... 
INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."track_id" = "tracks"."id"
WHERE "profiles"."id" = $1
```

### Update 2

Thanks for pointing out that the relation was non-existing between tracks and profiles, how about rearranging the structure?

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :profile_tracks
  has_many :tracks, through: :profile_tracks
end

class ProfileTrack < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
  has_many :tracks
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile_track
end
```

that would allow you to access both `track_ids` and `profile_track_ids` from Profile

Comment: This one will return associations where `track_id = 1`. But I also need `profile_id`. Where should it be placed in query?

Comment: I missed the point here my apologies, just updated my answer.

Comment: I see your update. But `profiles` table doesn't have `track_id` column. (`Can't join 'Track' to association named 'profiles'`)

Comment: Hi, as mentioned previously I would try a different approach to relations here, I hope that helps

Comment: `Track has_many :profile_tracks` and `ProfileTrack belongs_to :track`.

Comment: So if you would have an association between Profile and a Track, for Profile you can do a join on Track and with that you should be able to access `profile_track_ids` etc.

Comment: I came up with a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653718/14287993). But thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with raw SQL and `UNION`:

```
track = Track.find_by(id: 1)

a =
  track
  .profile_tracks
  .where(profile_id: 1)
  .select("id as value, 'profile_track_id' as key")
  .to_sql

b =
  track
  .favorite_tracks
  .where(profile_id: 1)
  .select("id as value, 'favorite_track_id' as key")
  .to_sql

c =
  track
  .bookmark_tracks
  .where(profile_id: 1)
  .select("id as value, 'bookmark_track_id' as key")
  .to_sql

d =
  track
  .listened_tracks
  .where(profile_id: 1)
  .select("id as value, 'listened_track_id' as key")
  .to_sql

ActiveRecord::Base
  .connection
  .execute("#{a} UNION #{b} UNION #{c} UNION #{d}")
  .to_a
  .map {|a| { a['key'] => a['value']}}
  .inject(:merge)
```